# Object is not a matrix error using cragg package and map in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use this function from the cragg package and iterate it using map but I keep getting the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) :    object is
> not a matrix

My code and reproducible example:

```
y <- data.frame(gender = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), age = rnorm(100), vcam = rnorm(100), 
                rs6696259 = rbinom(100, 2, 0.5), rs5491 = rbinom(100, 2, 0.5))

map(c("rs6696259", "rs5491"), ~
      cragg_donald(X =~ gender + age,
             D =~ vcam,
             Z =~ .x %>% as.name(),
             data = y))
```

However this line of coding works just fine.

```
cragg_donald(X =~ gender + age,
                     D =~ vcam,
                     Z =~ rs6696259,
                     data = y)
```

Thank you.